# Getting values from PHP page to Controller (AngularJS)

Tags: php, angularjs, controller, return

I want to compare a value inside of my `controller` (`angularjs`) but didn't want to make it using only `javascript` code.  Because it would be considered "weak", once anyone could see it.

What's the best way to check a value using `JS` and `PHP`?

Is it possible to send a request and have a return from the PHP page to my JS controller?

```
app.controller('headerController',function($scope){
    valueFromView = $scope.value.property;

    //send a request to the php page and get the value back from it

    if(this value from PHP == valueFromView){
      //my dream come true
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry if I said anything senseless... I'm an AngularJS beginner!

Comment: What you're looking for is called `ajax`. AngularJS uses the `$http` methods to `get` and `post` data back to the server.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually trying to find a way to have "both", get and post, at the same time. But just realized I can use ´get.url?using=this´ to send data and then have the response from the php code back as a true or false statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do an api on the server side with PHP that returns the data you would like to post, and then do the comparing client-side.

you can learn about how to accomplish here https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp